# Remove object with multiple angles of its background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal, photography

I have this image:

[image]

My goal is to remove the pillars on the side of the edge of the image so that it looks something like this: (I did a terrible clone job)

[image]

I have the a photo taken at a different angle:

[image]

Are there tools in photoshop that can help me achieve my goal?

Comment: Hi Tinker, Please edit your [origial question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145026/how-can-i-fill-a-brick-pattern-background) if you wish to supply additional information. Don't post the same question multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: I will close my previous question

Comment: Tinker, don't do that :) I already closed this one. :) **Edit** the previous question :)